# React spring transition setting 'none' to transform in enter

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

Does anyone have idea about how to set react spring transition css transform value to "none" in enter prop. What I m trying to do here is I need to change transform value into "none" based on my layout.

```
<Route 
        render={({ location, ...rest }) => (

            <Transition
                native
                items={location}
                keys= {location.pathname.split('/')[1]}
                // from= {{ opacity: 0 }}
                // enter={{ opacity: 1 }}
                // leave={{ opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%" }}
                from={{ opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(100%,0,0)' }}
                enter={[
                    { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate3d(0%,0,0)' },
                    { transform: 'none', immediate: true}
                ]}
                leave={{ opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(-50%,0,0)', position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%" }}
            >
                 {(loc, state) => style => (   
                    <Switch location={state === 'update' ? location : loc}>
                        <Route exact path="/" 
                            render={(props) => <HomePage style={style} catalogs={data} />} />
                        
                        <Route path="/about-us"
                            render={(props) => <AboutUsPage style={style} />} 
                        />
                        <Route path="/contact" 
                            render={(props) => <ContactPage style={style} />} 
                        />             
                        <Route path="/checkout" 
                            render={(props) => <CheckoutPage style={style} />} 
                        />    
                        
                        <Route
                            render={(props) => <NotFoundPage style={style} />} 
                        />                            
                    </Switch>
                 )}
            </Transition>
        )} 
    />
```

The problem is when I redirect to another view, there is error messages shown on console:

> Uncaught TypeError: entry.interpolation.calc is not a function
> at renderprops.js:1189
> at Array.reduce ()
> at Controller.update (renderprops.js:1171)
> at Spring.render (renderprops.js:1541)
> at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17485)
> at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:17435)
> at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19073)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056)
> at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964)
> at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776)
> at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707)
> at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670)
> at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293)
> at react-dom.development.js:11327
> at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:646)
> at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276)
> at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322)
> at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309)
> at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22420)
> at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756)
> at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889) (anonymous) @ renderprops.js:1189 update @ renderprops.js:1171 render
> @ renderprops.js:1541 finishClassComponent @
> react-dom.development.js:17485 updateClassComponent @
> react-dom.development.js:17435 beginWork @
> react-dom.development.js:19073 callCallback @
> react-dom.development.js:3945 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
> react-dom.development.js:3994 invokeGuardedCallback @
> react-dom.development.js:4056 beginWork$1 @
> react-dom.development.js:23964 performUnitOfWork @
> react-dom.development.js:22776 workLoopSync @
> react-dom.development.js:22707 renderRootSync @
> react-dom.development.js:22670 performSyncWorkOnRoot @
> react-dom.development.js:22293 (anonymous) @
> react-dom.development.js:11327 unstable_runWithPriority @
> scheduler.development.js:646 runWithPriority$1 @
> react-dom.development.js:11276 flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl @
> react-dom.development.js:11322 flushSyncCallbackQueue @
> react-dom.development.js:11309 discreteUpdates$1 @
> react-dom.development.js:22420 discreteUpdates @
> react-dom.development.js:3756 dispatchDiscreteEvent @
> react-dom.development.js:5889 index.js:1 The above error occurred in
> the  component:
>
> ```
> at Spring (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:57878:5)
> at KeyframesImpl (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:58089:5)
> at Transition (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:58257:5)
> at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:53390:29)
> at SwitchRouteBlock (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:2147:89)
> at div
> at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:53025:30)
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:52645:35)
> at CartProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5546:5)
> at FFMenuContextProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5866:5)
> at Main
> ```
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error
> handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to
> learn more about error boundaries.

I have no idea about this, I have spent couple of days on this, so please does anyone give me hands on this.
Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

After digging deep from google, I figured it out by this way,

```
  let _transform = transform.interpolate( ( t ) => { 
                            console.log(t);
                            return( t === 'translate3d(0%,0,0)' ? 'none' : t ) 
                        })
```

we can use transform.interpolate to set 'none' value, and pass into children component.

Example code below:

```
<Route 
            render={({ location, ...rest }) => (
                <Transition
                    native
                    items={location}
                    //keys= {location.pathname.split('/')[1]}
                    //We use pathname as key here
                    keys= {location.pathname}

                    // from= {{ opacity: 0 }}
                    // enter={{ opacity: 1 }}
                    // leave={{ opacity: 0, position: 'absolute', top: 0, left: 0, width: "100%" }}
                    from={{ opacity: 0, transform: 'translate3d(100%,0,0)' }}
                    enter={[
                        { opacity: 1, transform: 'translate3d(0%,0,0)' },
                        // { transform: 'none', immediate: true}
                    ]}
                    leave={{ 
                        opacity: 0, 
                        transform: 'translate3d(-50%,0,0)', 
                        position: 'absolute', 
                        top: 0, 
                        left: 0, 
                        width: "100%" 
                    }}
                >
                    {(loc, state) => ({transform, ...style}) => {   

                        //console.log(transform.interpolate((t)=>(t)));
                        let _transform = transform.interpolate( ( t ) => { 
                            console.log(t);
                            return( t === 'translate3d(0%,0,0)' ? 'none' : t ) 
                        })
                        

                        return(
                            <Switch location={state === 'update' ? location : loc}>
                                <Route exact path="/" 
                                    render={(props) => <HomePage style={{...style, transform : _transform}} catalogs={data} />} />
                                
                                <Route path="/about-us"
                                    render={(props) => <AboutUsPage style={{...style, transform : _transform}} />} 
                                />
                                <Route path="/contact" 
                                    render={(props) => <ContactPage style={{transform : _transform, ...style}} />} 
                                />             
                                <Route path="/checkout" 
                                    render={(props) => <CheckoutPage style={{transform : _transform, ...style}} />} 
                                />    
                                    
                                <Route
                                    render={(props) => <NotFoundPage style={{transform : _transform, ...style}} />} 
                                />                            
                            </Switch>
                        )
                    }}
                </Transition>
            )} 
        />
```

Hope this could help someone, or if anyone does have better solution, that will be great to leave here.